# Regex pattern for extracting substring from dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, python-3.8

I have a dataframe column as follows:

```
df['col1']

['cat-dog asd-pwr sdf', 'cat-goat asd-pwr2 sdf', 'cat asd-pwr3 sdf']
```

I need to extract the following:

```
['asd-pwr', 'asd-pwr2', 'asd-pwr3']
```

i.e the last pair of substrings which are connected by `-`

I tried the following:

```
import re
df['col1'].str.extract(r'\s[a-zA-Z]*-[a-zA-Z]*\s', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

First of all, my regex construct even fails to spot any pair of substrings as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['cat-dog asd-pwr sdf', 'cat-goat asd-pwr2 sdf', 'cat asd-pwr3 sdf']})
>>> df['col1'].str.extract(r'(?:.*\W)?(\w+-\w+)')
          0
0   asd-pwr
1  asd-pwr2
2  asd-pwr3
```

Or, if there can be start of string or whitespace on the left, you may also use

```
r'(?:.*\s)?(\w+-\w+)'
```

*Details*:

- `(?:.*\W)?` - an optional sequence of any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possibel, then a non-word char (`\s` matches a whitespace)
- `(\w+-\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars, `-` and one or more word chars.

As `.*` is greedy, the last part of the pattern between round brackets (aka capturing parentheses) gets the last occurrence of hyphenated words.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
import re

df['col1'].str.extract(r'\s*(\w+-\w+)(?!.*-)\s*', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Here, we use `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z]` because you also want to extract the number after `pwr`.

We also use negative lookahead `(?!.*-)` to ensure the current matching substring is the last substring with hyphen `-` in the string.

Result:

```
          0
0   asd-pwr
1  asd-pwr2
2  asd-pwr3
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do the trick

```
\w*-\w*(?=(\s|$)\w*.*$)
```

Only take the last object from the resulting match array.